# Wrong base URL in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm working on a payment system that runs in a UIWebView. The user completes a form on one site, and is taken to a payment gateway to process their card information. Once the payment has been processed, the user is taken back to a confirmation page on the first site.

The sites work as expected when tested in a normal browser, or even Mobile Safari. The sites are black boxes, and I can't change anything inside them. Apparently, the sites use relative URLs, and my issue occurs because my UIWebView is trying to load a page on the second domain with the base URL from the first domain.

For example,

1. User posts form from http://theform.com/page
2. User is taken to http://theform.com/OrderCC.aspx?orderRef=e59d7f53a693472cad8a76dd8fb64

In the second step, the user *should* have been taken to http://thepaymentgateway.com/OrderCC.aspx...

I'm trying to intercept requests to the wrong base URL, and reroute them to a correct one like this:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {

  NSString *wrongURL = @"http://theform.com/OrderCC.aspx";
  NSString *request = [[inRequest URL] absoluteString];

  NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[inRequest HTTPBody] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

  if ([request length] >= 33 && [[request substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 33)] isEqualToString:wrongURL]) {
    [webView loadData:[inRequest HTTPBody] MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://thepaymentgateway.com/OrderCC.aspx%@", [request substringFromIndex:33]]]];
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

After this runs, it seems my UIWebView is just displaying a blank page containing the POST data string. Where am I going wrong?